# How do we recognise a Hybridised Sp3 orbital?

Tags: orbitals, hybridization

As far as i know the sp3 orbital is a combination of orbitals. But how do we know if we have a hybridised orbital or not?

Comment: There are ways to determine bond lengths (via X-Ray diffraction or, Neutron diffraction) and if bond lengths are found to be equal in a place where we predict it to be by hybridisation, you can say the orbitals are hybridised.

Comment: Not an answe but maybe it highlights a bit about sp-hybridizations https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/89214/draw-a-diagram-to-show-the-shape-of-chloromethane-and-explain-why-it-has-this-sh/89224#89224